# Redireccionar web a una carpeta diferente de public_html

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo contratado un servicio de Cloud Hosting.

Y necesito que mi dominio deje de apuntar a `/home/admin/public_html` y apunte a `/home/admin/public_html/moodle` o alguna otra carpeta.

Consultando con el servicio técnico de mi proveedor de hosting me dijeron que hiciera una redirección 301 en el archivo `.htaccess`

Lo que no sé es cuáles deberían ser las líneas de código que debo escribir en este archivo.

El contenido actual de mi archivo `.htaccess` es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?midominio\.com RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Aprecio tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un archivo en el servidor con la extensión **`.conf`** en ese archivo debes actualizar la ruta de moodle así:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/moodle
```

Espero te haya ayudado.